# how to display my WordPress plugin on a chosen page?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm new to WordPress development and I just can't get my head around rendering the actual html/css contents on my plugin to a page on my WP site. Is there a specific function or so? I'm not talking about widgets.

An example would be a plugin that displays a jpeg image or a plugin that displays the html/css for a chatbox. How do I actually render that visual output on a chosen WP page on my site?

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use functions like `add_action()` or `add_filter()`.

Suppose you want to add a plugin's functionality after the content of each blog post, use:

```
add_action( 'the_content', 'plugins_function_name' );
```